# How does owin middleware track change in cookie

Tags: owin, openid-connect

How does owin middleware track change in cookie? I am using cookie authentication. After cookie is generated and attached to browser if I make any change in cookie by using F12(developer toolbar in browser) and send request to sever how is owin validating cookie?

```
 var cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieName = "test",
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12),
            SlidingExpiration = false

        };

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

**PREFERRED BEHAVIOR**

Auth cookies are strongly encrypted since they contain tokens in some cases. The pattern for auth cookies is to use properties such as these:

- HTTP Only
- Encrypted
- SameSite=strict
- Domain=web origin
- Secure

Symmetric authenticated encryption is used, with an algorithm such as AES256-GCM. This means any edit to any cookie byte will fail decryption, resulting in a 401 error. You should test this.

Cookies are time restricted also. Either the `exp` claim of stored tokens is checked on every request, or a separate timestamp within the cookie data.

**OWIN**

Sone notes [here](https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/asp-net-has-no-magic-encryption-and-decryption-of-asp-net-identity-and-identity-encryption-and-decryption_1_50_32765022.html) on OWIN crypto. It is quite an old tech now, so does not use the most cutying edge encryption algorithms. Instead it uses machine key based encryption, which I believe uses AES + HMACSHA under the hood. The end result is essentially the same behavior as above though.

Comment: Gary, thanks for response, I am talking about once cookie is generated and attached to browser. I can do F12(open developer tool bar) and under Application/Cookie identify  cookie by name and edit existing cookie by typing some random text. When I do this and make request to sever it is redirecting to SSO identiysever? How openidconnect is triggering RedirectToIdentityProvider? What is server checking for cookie tempering or validation?

Comment: You can see how that works from the [siurce code](https://github.com/c4net/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L121) - an edited cookie is treated the same as a missing cookie.